# Is the Schwarz inequality a special case of the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, inequality

Given two vectors $\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$, we all know that:$$\left | \mathbf{x}\cdot\mathbf{y} \right | \le \left \| \mathbf{x} \right \| \cdot\left \| \mathbf{y} \right \| \tag{1}$$

Another similar form for this inquality is:$$\left\vert \int_a^bfg\hspace{2pt} \right\vert\le\left(\int_a^bf^2\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}\left(\int_a^bg^2\right)^{\frac{1}{2}} \tag{2}$$

Is 1 a special case of 2? If so, for which functions $f,g$?

See [this](https://books.google.it/books?id=7JKVu_9InRUC&pg=PA278&lpg=PA278&dq=spivak+calculus+show+Schwarz+inequality+is+a+special+case+of+cauchy+inequality&source=bl&ots=wkKKCnEZPg&sig=5Yf7Awdu-5eGW6RCWiaIMuCcuxU&hl=it&sa=X&ei=1zuaVbmCNMPy-QH0nKOoBA&ved=0CEAQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=spivak%20calculus%20show%20Schwarz%20inequality%20is%20a%20special%20case%20of%20cauchy%20inequality&f=false) [Non-OP edit: As of 14 May 2018: this link can't be viewed.]

Comment: @BolzWeir what about the link above?

Comment: @BolzWeir Is Spivak wrong?

Comment: $f(t) = x_{k}$ for $k-1 < t \leqslant k$ on $[0,n]$.

Comment: @DanielFischer What about $g$?

Comment: Can you make an educated guess?

Comment: @DanielFischer I'll try :)

Answer (score 0):

As written now (integral on the interval $[a,b]$) isn't. But in a more general context ([measure theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measure_(mathematics))), both (1) and (2) are particular cases of a [more general theorem](http://www.probability.net/WEBspaces.pdf):
$$
\left|\int_X fg\,d\mu\right|^2\le
\left(\int_X f^2\,d\mu\right)\left(\int_X g^2\,d\mu\right)
$$
(1) is the particular case where the space is a finite set with a discrete uniform measure. In (2) we have an interval with the Lebesgue measure.